# JSON Object name returning as ID

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular and .NET Core.  In my web application that I'm building I have two objects that are returned on my Organization Detail page.  They are as follows:

- Organization (retrieved via the API and gives details about an organization such as OrganizationName, StreetAddress, PhoneNumber, FirstName, LastName and so on)
- OwnedLocations (A list of all locations an organization owns and details on those locations.  IE: LocationName, ContactFirstName, ContactLastName, PhoneNumber, StreetAddress and so on).

I am facing a problem though when these details are retrieved.  They are being listed in the returned json object with a name of 1[image]

The Organization is called based on its ID in the database.  The OwnedLocations are called based on all locations owned by the organizations ID.  Is there a way to list them under a different name instead of the ID? Here are the relevant files:

OrganizationDetailComponent.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Organizations } from '../../../../_models/organizations';
import { AlertifyService } from '../../../../_services/alertify.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../../../_services/auth.service';
import { OrganizationService } from '../../../../_services/Organization.service';
import { LocationService } from '../../../../_services/location.service';
import { Locations } from '../../../../_models/locations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-organization-detail',
  templateUrl: './organization-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./organization-detail.component.scss']
})
export class OrganizationDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('editForm', {static: true}) editForm: NgForm;
  organizations: Organizations;
  orgLocations: Locations[];
  currentDate = new Date();
  isActive = false;
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  unloadNotidication($event: any) {
    if (this.editForm.dirty) {
      $event.returnValue = true;
    }
  }

  constructor(private organizationService: OrganizationService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router, private authService: AuthService, private locationService: LocationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getOrgLocations();

    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.organizations = data['organization'];
    });
  }

  loadOrganization() {
    this.organizationService.GetOrganization(+this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe((organization: Organizations) => {
      this.organizations = organization;
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }

  getOrgLocations() {
    this.locationService.getOwnedLocations(+this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe((orgLocations: Locations) => {
      orgLocations = orgLocations;
      console.log(orgLocations);
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }

  updateClient() {
    this.organizationService.updateOrganization(this.organizations.id, this.organizations).subscribe(next => {
      this.alertify.success('Client updated successfully');
      this.editForm.reset(this.loadOrganization());
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }
}


  getOrgLocations() {
    this.locationService.getOwnedLocations(+this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe((orgLocations: Locations) => {
      orgLocations = orgLocations;
      console.log(orgLocations);
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }

  updateClient() {
    this.organizationService.updateOrganization(this.organizations.id, this.organizations).subscribe(next => {
      this.alertify.success('Client updated successfully');
      this.editForm.reset(this.loadOrganization());
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Location.Service.ts

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Locations } from '../_models/locations';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LocationService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getLocations(): Observable<Locations[]> {
    return this.http.get<Locations[]>(this.baseUrl + 'locations', httpOptions);
  }

  getOwnedLocations(id): Observable<Locations> {
    return this.http.get<Locations>(this.baseUrl + 'locations/getorglocations/' + id, httpOptions);
  }

  getLocation(id): Observable<Location> {
    return this.http.get<Location>(this.baseUrl + 'locations/' + id, httpOptions);
  }

  CreateLocations(location: Locations) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'locations', location, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        const locationId = response;
        if (locationId) {
          return locationId;
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Organization.Service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Organizations } from '../_models/organizations';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class OrganizationService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getOrganizations(): Observable<Organizations[]> {
    return this.http.get<Organizations[]>(this.baseUrl + 'organizations', httpOptions);
  }

  GetOrganization(id): Observable<Organizations> {
    return this.http.get<Organizations>(this.baseUrl + 'organizations/' + id, httpOptions);
  }

  updateOrganization(id: number, organization: Organizations) {
    return this.http.put(this.baseUrl + 'organizations/' + id, organization);
  }

  CreateOrganization(organization: Organizations) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'organizations', organization)
    .pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        const organizationId = response;
        if (organizationId) {
          return organizationId;
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is showing as `1` for both requests because that is end-point of both the URLs.

```js
this.http.get<Location>(this.baseUrl + 'locations/' + id, httpOptions);
```

```js
this.http.get<Organizations>(this.baseUrl + 'organizations/' + id, httpOptions);
```

The browser's network page usually displays the requests using their end-points. Which in your case would be `id` for both the URLs. However the URL itself isn't the same. They also return different objects based on the mentioned types (`Location` and `Organizations`). So the JSON handling **wouldn't be affected** in the front-end.

You could if you wish filter the requests using any part of the URL in the browser's network page. For eg., if you filter using keyword `locations`, only one `1` would be shown which would correspond to the URL `this.baseUrl + 'locations/' + id`. Likewise, using keyword `organizations` would show only one `1` for the URL `this.baseUrl + 'organizations/' + id`.

Comment: Hey Michael. I have just discovered that and changed the API endpoint from locations/{id} to reflect {id}/locations.  and then adjusted the locations.service.ts to reflect the change in the API endpoint.  This has resolved it for me.  I just learnt something new :P. 

Thanks again!